# Magento2 : Add Simple Products to bundle product selection

Tags: magento2, import, programmatically, bundle-product

I have a bundle product created from Admin Section. Now I am updating inventory of simple products i.e adding products to Magento Catalog Programmatically via CSV file.

I want to add those simple product as a bundle product selections. I have already created its option name "Clothes".

Please help me how I can proceed.

I have searched other question on stackexchange but nothing worked for me so first understand my problem it is different from others(For those who mark questions to duplicate).